# How to access javascript sessionStorage in to Rails Controller as session

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session

I set `sessionStorage.setItem("origin_url", window.location.href);` in my js file and then I tried to access it in rails controller via  `session[:origin_url]` and it didn't work. No error and I put logger.info to `session[:origin_url]` and nothing displays on it.

How could I access the sessionStorage from JS to Rails?

Comment: how are you sending the sessionStorage object to your rails controller? Could you post some code?

Comment: I'm not sending it, because I thought it is a session where I can access it anywhere in my site like cookies.

Comment: sessionStorage is not like cookies. Different tabs/windows don't share the same sessionStorage. You can only share sessionStorage on same tab/windows for same site (under the same site, the same protocol and the same port)

Comment: yes but. is there a way that I can set session in javascript and access it in rails server?

Comment: sessionStorage store data in the local browser, you can't access it from the server side. Why don't you use cookies instead if you want both client and server can access the same set of data?

Comment: Okey then, I will do the cookies. I tried session because as we know it will not last when browser is closed, and I want to take advantage of it supposedly. But right now I understand, I will work with cookies, thankyou all.

Answer (score -1):

Session is server side. You need to set it on server by passing the browser session data to some controller & then access from there